# Stream audio from speakers to mp3 for iphone/internet radio?

Tags: iphone, streaming, mp3, expression-encoder, internet-radio

I want to stream the audio that comes out of my speakers on my computer (windows) through an mp3 file that I can access on my iphone and hear the audio/music through safari or a 3rd party app. How would I do this?

Comment: By... *asking someplace else*? I'd suggest, given the iPhone connection, [the Apple Stack Exchange Site](http://apple.stackexchange.com/), or, at a pinch, [Super User](http://superuser.com/), but I'd expect closure at SU if I'm entirely honest. The Apple guys may take more kindly to it, though...I *am*, by the by, sorry for my vote-to-close, it does seem churlish, but the question *is* (imho) *way* off-topic. Better luck elsewhere!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wifi2hifi app: http://www.wifi2hifi.com/

On the computer you install the free WiFi2HiFi Station. It streams whatever audio is played.